# How can I generate an ID in Sybase SQL before inserting rows

Tags: java, sql, transactions, sap-ase, spring-transactions

I have a distributed system where I need to generate an ID and then use that ID in multiple records. The records reference each other so I rather not insert the master to generate an ID followed by the children

What I am hoping to do is generate a unique ID in sequence from Sybase, use that ID to create all of my associated records, then perform all of the inserts in a batch update.

I can have a table with a single IDENTITY field, and just insert records there and get the generated ID. However with that approach I am creating lots of useless records.

I tried this approach but it throws an exception

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
  public synchronized Long getNextId(){

  Long id = -1;
  String sql = "UPDATE MY_IDS SET MY_ID=MY_ID+1\n\n" +
               "SELECT MY_ID FROM MY_IDS";
  List<Long> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException
    {
        return resultSet.getLong(1);
    }
  });
  if(!list.isEmpty()) {
      id = list.get(0);
  }
  return id;
 }
```

I also tried this but also got a SQL exception:

```
KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

    String sql = "UPDATE MY_IDS SET MY_ID=MY_ID+1" +
                 "SELECT MY_ID FROM MY_IDS";
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        return ps;
    }
}, holder);

Long id = holder.getKey().longValue();
```

Is there a more straightforward way

Answer (score 0):

newid() func didn't worked for me. I found another solution

```
with queryname as (
SELECT *,row_number() over (order by somecol) n, -- get row number
DATEPART(ms, now()) t -- get current ms value
FROM sometable )

select top 10 * from queryname order by  cast(t * n as char)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
1> select newid(),newid(1)
2> go

 ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
 086ae8a4920944dcb45f81b8c983b3f1     3c23dabf-d989-48dc-807b-81b8c983b3f1
```

Comment: Some explanation here would be helpful. It's not clear if this is supposed to be an answer, a new question, or a comment.

Comment: OP wanted a way to generate a unique id.   I'm suggesting that the "newid()" built-in may of be some use here.    So, if interested, the original poster can simply lookup this builtin in the Sybase docs and proceed from there :)

Comment: I'd suggest adding that explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are not always clear. :)

Comment: you're right.  but i didn't take the poster for an idiot, but rather a data processing professional capable of understanding a suggested solution when he sees one. ;)

Comment: I'm not saying OP is an idiot, nor am I saying that you said OP is an idiot. I am saying, however, that this answer is not very complete and likely to attract downvotes and flags. In fact, it already has gotten both. You might want to read about [answer] questions here.

Comment: you're the downvoter no doubt.  with a bit too much time on your hands to constantly badger a willing contributor.  Please move on

Comment: Just trying to help you out as a new user. You have multiple downvotes because your answer isn't up to the site's standards, and you have proven uninterested in improving it. I'm just offering friendly advice. Do with it as you wish. You might also want to check out the ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: The reviewer didn't request clarification.  Only the site cops did.  It's over.  Please, please, I get it.  Let's carry on.

Comment: EDIT:  The "requester" didn't request clarification